# Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE auto focus on take picture

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, autofocus

We were using Camera API for our custom camera application. However, it turned out to be a very hard problem. Many devices required extra testing as they seemed to perform unexpected behaviors. So, we have decided to migrate to Android's camera intent.

However, we are dealing with image retrieval tasks so, we don't want our users to send us blurry pictures. Previously, we were using autofocus as user taps on take picture button. Android camera intent performs worse than ours because it does not try to autofocus just before taking the picture. Android's camera does have such option but we don't want leave that decision up to our users because, they will probably will not select that option.

Is it possible to launch the camera intent with the option which auto focusses just before taking the picture? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to launch the camera intent with the option which auto focusses just before taking the picture?

No. The decision of whether or not to use auto-focus, or a flash, or any other camera feature, is between the user and the developers of the camera app. You do not get a vote.

Comment: That's a shame :/. Thanks for the answer!